# sqlite is given me headache in my C#2.0 windows application

Tags: c#, sqlite, connection-string

I'm struggling since this morning about this sqlite thing.after reading some good tutorials i decided to   use it as my embedded database in my winform application.
i downloaded SQLite-1.0.61.0-setup that install the system.datal.sqlite for me and downloaded the firefox plugin sqlite manager and another management tool called wxSQLitePlus found [here](http://cfred.free.fr/wxsqliteplus.php) based on this tutorials found [here](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/using-sqlite-with-net/) (just being explicit)
Hoping i'm not posting any stupid stuff that will be ignored, here are my 2 challenges.
the first challenge is that i can't reference the database inside a folder let'say database
i have exception "Unable to open the database file".my app.config is as follow

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="embcon" connectionString="Data Source=database\iagency.db;Version=3;"/>
```

but if the iagency.db is inside the root folder there is no problem at all.app.config like

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="embcon" connectionString="Data Source=iagency.db;Version=3;"/>
```

the second chalenge is that object created via tools such as either firefox plugin or wxsqlite+
cannot be queried inside visual studio 2005 that i'm using.if it's a table when queried , i have an excetion the object doesn't exist even though both tools displays the same data.
and inversly table created by queries inside visual studio cannot be viewed by the tools.
so what's the deal?
is it a memory stuff or i'm just missing some points?
can enybody explain what is happening ?Thanks for reading.

Comment: WAG... I'd try .\database\iagency.db as well as with the forward slashes (database/iagency.db etc)

Comment: thanks for your time you spent giving me some ideas.i appreciate it.i'll deal with the path stuff later.Right now i still can't query a table created outside visual stutio.i thought it was the system.data.sqlite(from sqlado.net provider 2.0) that is having issues.but i successfully created tables from vs gui database tools.but still i can't query that database inside vs with query like select * from users.it says the table does not exit even though  i can see the table from vs server explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full filepath as the data source (e.g. Data Source=c:\data\iagency.db)

See this post for more: [datasource location in connection string](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/123/436.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply.i'm not sure that post solve my problems but it gives me some idea about it.for the url i tried data source=.\database\iagency.db but it doesn't seem to find it.what about the fact i can't see the object for an sqlite explorer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
<add name="embcon" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\iagency.db;Version=3;"/>
```